# How to decide which penalty measure to use ? any general guidelines or thumb rules out of textbook

Tags: machine-learning, lasso, ridge-regression, regularization

A number of [regularization measures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_(mathematics)) are available in literatures, which is kind of confusing to beginners. The classical penalty is **ridge** by Hoerl & Kennard (1970,Technometrics 12, 55–67).

[image]

Another modification to this is **lasso** by Tibshirani (1996, Journal of the Royal Statis- tical Society B 58, 267–288), defined as:

[image]

Another penalty is the **elastic net penalty** (Zou and Hastie 2005, Journal of the Royal Statistical Society B 67, 301–320) , which is a linear combination of the lasso penalty and the ridge penalty. Therefore the penalty covers these both as extreme cases.
[image]

The another penalty that I could find is **bridge penalty**  introduced in Frank & Friedman (1993, Technometrics 35, 109–148). where λ ̃ = (λ, γ). It features an additional tuning parameter γ that controls the degree of preference for the estimated coefficient vector to align with the original, hence standardized, data axis direc- tions in the regressor space. It comprises the lasso penalty (γ = 1) and the ridge penalty (γ = 2) as special cases.

[image]

My question is : ***are there any preferences on type of penalty to use - something from or out of statistical text books*** ?  Or this is just trial and error ? Please explain to layman language.

Comment: The [no free lunch theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_free_lunch_theorem) might apply here? At least in terms of predictive power. The lasso penalty has the benefit of inducing sparseness if you're into that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be many considerations to this matter. 
To name a few:

1. Inference: the distribution of ridge estimates is fairly simple to derive. Lasso, and basically any other penalty that performs variable selection, has only limited probabilistic results.
2. Sparsity: If you desire a model with only a few predictors (say, for speed of prediction, for interpretability, ...) then you will want $l_1$ regularization.
3. Speed of computation: The time complexity of the learning can be a consideration. There are differences between the algorithms. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76518/what-is-the-time-complexity-of-lasso-regression) for some guidance. This becomes especially important if you plug the whole procedure in a cross validation scheme where models are fitted repeatedly.